# input()-style input from a PyQt form

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, user-input

I've created a PyQt application which essentially mimics a simple terminal (text-only display with a read-only QTextEdit, input with a QLineEdit which sends its content on the user pressing return), so that I can add extra display elements beside the faux-terminal.

Using the normal shell terminal, I can output text like so:

```
print("Hello world!")
```

This is relatively easy to replicate using the GUI:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    # Setup etc...

    def OnReturnPressed(self, e):

        # Linked to the appropriate signal of the LineEdit containing
        # user input

        input = self.GetLineEditContentsAndClear()
        MainCode(input, self.Output)

    def Output(self, text):
        # ...Outputs text to the display TextEdit


def MainCode(input, outputFuction)

    outputFunction("Hello World!")
```

Likewise, I can get input from the default terminal like so:

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
```

However, I have no idea how to do the equivalent using the GUI, since the main code (as in the Output example above) has to be triggered by the GUI input.

My current best attempt is to call the main code from the QWidget's QLineEdit "return key pressed" signal, passing whatever text is in the QLineEdit to the main code, and then to `return` from the main code whenever I need new input, but this leads to an absolute mess as I try to get back to the same point in code execution as I was when I `return`ed.

Is there any way to write an `input()`-like function to wait for input from the GUI and then return it and resume execution where it left off? What I **want** is to be able to do something like this:

```
import mygui  # Contains all necessary GUI code

def MainCode():

    # Setup and initialize GUI, then run it as a separate thread
    # or process
    #
    # For the sake of the example, call it 'myguiinstance'

    # Setup other stuff

    # Main Loop
    while(true):

        input = myguiinstance.GetInput("Enter input")
        # Puts the main code on hold until the GUI returns input.

        while not CheckIfInputIsValid(input) #Defined elsewhere
            input = myguiinstance.GetInput("Invalid input. Enter input:")

        output1, output2, output3 = ProcessInput(input)

        output = format("Foo: {0}\nBar: {1}\nFoobar: {2}",
            output1, output2, output3)
        myguiinstance.Output(output)
```

Comment: the context of your question is unclear, consider that we do not know your code or what it is, the common language between programmers is the code, so I ask you to show it, obviously this code should be minimal, but understandable . This is what we refer to when we ask that every good question must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies, I though that that was only for code that wasn't running/was throwing errors. I'm not sure how best to show the maze of workarounds I'm currently using as a code example, but I'll give it a think and update my question a little later.

Comment: from what I understand you think you want to have the same behavior as the input function in the console, what you did is put it in a loop, receive the input, process it and then show the result. I am right? o Another thing is to create your own python console similar to those that have IDE, which of the 2 options you want. Very apart from that in a GUI it is not good that there is a loop since this has a general loop `app.exec_()`

Comment: @eyllanesc That is what I want, yes; input()-like function but from a custom GUI. The reason for the separate loop is that I want the GUI (running on the `app.exec_()` loop) and the main code to be separate, hence the separate main code execution loop.

Comment: you're using pyqt4 or pyqt5 to be able to show an example and tell me that's what you want.

Comment: try with this: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/787417ef62fc0bcd05bde10d02724e4e